# How to avoid self boring when programming patches

Tags: synthesis, psychoacoustics

I'm totally new in sound generation. I fdeel that when programming a patch to look for something 'magic' the sounds just became boring to ourself and we possibly miss the real point not just because we can't find the right sound, but just for we get the ear 'abused' with certain notes and unable to feel the right things. Does some technique to improve exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you let it play note on repeat when designing sound? I push the keyboard myself and I found that much better than let it loop the note and sculpting your sound.

I often can't resist to go wild with the keyboard too, which is fun and often rewards me with desirable sound.